# Converting and Writing Variable of Type Var to Output File

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I've got a pretty awful track record when it comes to trying to explain what I'm asking here, so hopefully I can be a little more clear with this one.

Basically, we are querying a client's database and returning a report based on it, then writing what is returned to a text file. But because what we're looking to write to said file is a 'var' rather than a 'string', I'm having a terrible time of it.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IndexedService>("WSHttpBinding_IndexedService",
endpointAddress);
var _Service = factory.CreateChannel();
var results = _Service.GetUserReportResults("login", criteria.ToArray(),
grouping, sortFields.ToArray(), userReport.UserReportId,
userReport.EntityModel, key);

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("test.txt"))
{
formatter.Serialize(stream, results);
}
```

I'm trying to write what is stored in `var results` to test.txt, and am trying to find the best way to do that. `BinaryFormatter` is where I am with that right now, for better or worse. It's the only route that's actually written anything viable, but even it is a clutter of ascii and other values scattered throughout.

Is there any information that my question may be lacking that would help to clarify what I'm asking? Details I may have taken for granted to be assumed? If so, I'll be happy to add them.

I realize this is probably (like most of mine) a fairly remedial question, and I'm probably missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to find anything out yet that helps me solve this, so any kind of help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT
I have tried

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserReportPreviewListDto));
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("serializer.xml");
serializer.Serialize(WriteFileStream, results);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

and

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("formatter.xml"))
{
formatter.Serialize(stream, results);
}
```

but wind up with an error reading

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
> Converter.exe
>
> Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

each time. Any thoughts/help?

Comment: `var` is not a type - it just means that the type is inferred by the compiler.  The actual type will be whatever `_Service.GetUserReportResults` returns.  If you know that type at design time you can use Xml or Json.

Comment: To add to what @DStanley says, if you hover above the var keyword it will tell you what type it has inferred.

Comment: Override ToString() on the type that _Service.GetUserReportResults returns

Comment: This would be one of those embarrassing things I should have known, isn't it?

It's type UserReportPreviewListDto[]. Is that any more helpful than I assume it not to be? Is there anything more helpful than that I can contribute?

Comment: The benefit is that you can now pass `typeof(UserReportPreviewListDto[])` to a `XmlSerializer` or `JsonSerializer` to serizlize the data into a human-readable format.

Comment: @DStanley , the XmlSerializer worked great, but now we need to make adjustments to the output. It's suggested that I use a DataTable for this. Do you happen to have any suggestions on how to best go about this? I'll be comparing one value against a database table, then changing its value accordingly.

Comment: @Eiketsu I'd ask that as a different question so you get more visibility.

Comment: @DStanley I actually *did*, and it had 25 views but no answers yesterday. Today, I can't even find it. It's not listed as asked in my profile or anything.

Comment: @Eiketsu This one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277407/using-sql-in-visual-studio-to-edit-xml-output

Comment: @DStanley That's the one. Any clue why that wouldn't show up in my profile?

Comment: @Eiketsu No - I can see it in your profile under "Questions" so I'm not sure why you can't (be aware that there are three different ways to sort questions).  You can "nudge" the question by editing it and adding more detail; or after 48 hours you (or someone else) can offer a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out great for me. Thank you for the help, everyone.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserReportPreviewListDto[]));
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("serializer.xml");
serializer.Serialize(WriteFileStream, results);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

Learned something awesome today that'll help out a ton in the future, I have no doubt. Thanks again!